# Why does その辺 mean “regular”?

Tags: word-usage

> 寿季「だって、なんというか……ずっと憧れの人だったわけで……」
>
> 桐葉「あら、そうなの？」
>
> 寿季「月見坂さんは俺のこと、**その辺**のファンだなぐらいに思っていただろうけど……」
>
> 寿季「俺は君が心の支えだった。そのぐらいまで月見坂ーー月見桐奈のことが好きだったから」
>
> 寿季「多分……このことが無かったら、俺は月見坂さんに告白していたと思うぐらいには」
>
> 桐葉「……そうなんだ。ちょっと照れちゃうわね」

Context: A girl called 月見坂桐葉 offers to become 寿季’s girlfriend. The girl is his schoolmate and is admired by 寿季.

I asked what this その辺 means elsewhere and a native speaker told me it meant “regular” in this context. I don’t know why it means that even if I know it originally means “thereabouts”. Or do you think it means something else there? Please shed some light on it.

If the context is insufficient, please let me know.

Comment: It's more like "just another fan" than "regular fan".

Answer (score 4):

その辺 literally means 'around there'. The implication is that you do not have to look too far, you can find 'it' anywhere so that it means 'regular' figuratively.

---

Note that その辺 can be used non-figuratively, literally referring to some particular area. E.g. その辺で買った can mean *I bought it around there* (*there* understood by context) or *The shop I bought it is fairly ordinary* (implying such a shop can be found anywhere).