# What's the difference between 其処ら, 至る所, and そこら中?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage

Trying to figure out how to say the word "everywhere" in Japanese, and I want to make sure I'm using the correct one. Usually there's some difference due to context or formality. Context of what I'm doing does not matter though, because I'd generally like to hear when and where to use each word.

Comment: I think context does matter here, because "everywhere" can be translated into a lot more than these three words, which together cover just a subset of the way the word is used in English. Some examples of what you wanted to convey might help. Otherwise, a good place to start for understanding "everywhere" constructions in Japanese would be here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13074/%e3%81%a9%e3%81%93%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82-vs-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%93%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82-vs-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%93%e3%82%82.

Answer (score 2):

其処{そこ}ら is ambiguous between *anywhere/any ordinary place* and *everywhere*. So it overlaps with the other two mostly in the same way *anywhere* and *everywhere* overlaps in English. For example, そこらでみられる literally means *can be seen anywhere* or just *common*, which can be *can be seen everywhere*. It is similar to そのへん (cf [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91399/45489)). On the other hand, そこらで買った means *bought around there*. Since buying happened at one place and not everywhere obviously, it is different from そこら中で買った (which, being less likely, means *bought things everywhere*).

至る所 and 其処ら中 means *everywhere/all over the place* and are interchangeable as far as I can think of. The latter is perhaps more colloquial due to the nature of そこら.